# Is PHP CLI on Windows hardcoded for cmd.exe, or can I somehow make it use PowerShell?

Tags: php, windows, powershell, shell-exec

I'm using PHP CLI on Windows. Up until recently, I've always used .bat files to start PHP scripts ("php test.php", basically), which uses the cmd.exe terminal. For numerous reasons, I'm trying to migrate to PowerShell, which unlike cmd.exe is not officially deprecated or "semi-deprecated". I have had numerous problems with this, but this is specifically in regards to PHP CLI.

Basically, if I use a .ps1 script (that's PowerShell v1, which I believe is the current version of PowerShell) to run a PHP script (again, "php test.php"), it starts in PowerShell as expected, but if I then use any of the shell_exec() or similar functions in PHP to open new PHP scripts, it always seems to default to using cmd.exe instead of PowerShell.

One "workaround" seems to be to explicitly call:

```
powershell actualcommand
```

But this is not the same thing as *actually* using PowerShell. It seems to be more like embedding PowerShell into a cmd.exe terminal. I wish to exclusively use PowerShell instead of cmd.exe from PHP. I've searched and searched but I can't find any kind of php.ini setting or anything of the sort which would instruct PHP as to which terminal to use.

What is the correct way to make PHP CLI use a specific shell/binary for terminal-related stuff? Or is it hardcoded to cmd.exe on Windows?

Comment: powershell.exe, cmd.exe, and php.exe are console applications, which means they either inherit a console (from the parent process) or allocate a new console (if the parent doesn't have one or if created with a flag that forces it). A console is a system resource. In Windows 7+, each console is hosted by an instance of conhost.exe.

Comment: What makes you think that "it always seems to default to using cmd.exe"? And ... why would you `shell_exec()` to execute php from... within php?

Comment: What do you mean by a ps1 script starts PHP "in PowerShell as expected"? Do you mean the script runs in powershell_ise.exe, i.e. the integrated scripting environment?

Comment: None of your comments make any sense. Please address the question.

Comment: My guess is that PHP is using the `ComSpec` environment variable to run shell commands, but changing this to PowerShell may have unintended/unanticipated consequences. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I'm just trying to make PHP always use PowerShell instead of cmd.exe, because it currently launches cmd.exe windows if you use shell_exec and friends. And the reason I need to switch to PowerShell is simply that cmd.exe is in "legacy" state and will at some point be removed entirely. But sadly, even PowerShell doesn't seem to have proper support for Unicode, so it doesn't exactly feel like a big "upgrade"... only a necessary one.

Comment: You're conflating terminals/consoles and shells. If php.exe is run from Explorer, it will either briefly flash a console window or run a REPL shell in one. Whatever it does, the window you see is a system console that's hosted by conhost.exe and has absolutely nothing at all to do with cmd.exe. Also, the shell that gets used by C `system` or PHP `shell_exec` has nothing at all to do with any console or terminal and nothing to do with the parent process (i.e. CMD or PowerShell), unless it's changing the value of the `ComSpec` environment variable, which should point to cmd.exe or equivalent.

Comment: If I understand, you are saying, "just because I want to," but you don't really have a specific problem that this would fix. What is the cost/benefit for doing this?

Comment: As an aside re _PowerShell v1, which I believe is the current version of PowerShell_: Windows PowerShell's current (and final) version is 5.1, and PowerShell _Core_'s is 6.x as of this writing (the upcoming v7 will drop the "Core" qualifier); they all still use `.ps1` as the script filename extension, so as to indicate backward compatibility all the way back to v1 (for the most part).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: Changing the default shell to one with an incompatible CLI / syntax would indeed be a bad idea. PHP (fortunately, in this case) ignores `ComSpec`.

Comment: @mklement0: I agree, it's a bad idea (hence my line of questioning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a way to make PHP use *PowerShell* instead of `cmd.exe` as the shell in functions such as `system()` and `shell_exec()`.

Given that PowerShell is increasingly supplanting `cmd.exe`, that desire is understandable - why not move to PowerShell in *all* aspects?

Unfortunately, doing so would be a massively breaking change, because existing code with `system()` / `shell_exec()` calls that were written for `cmd.exe` is likely to break, given that `cmd.exe` and PowerShell have fundamentally different syntax.

All existing scripting languages that offer functionality for running shell commands face this problem.

<sup>As an aside: A more fundamental problem is that code that runs shell commands is *platform-specific*.</sup>

Even if there were an *opt-in* way to change the default shell - and there isn't  - it would have to be scoped to *your* code, so as not to break third-party code.

Generally speaking, there are only two ways for a scripting language to make this transition:

- Commit to breaking backward compatibility, requiring all code to be (re)written for PowerShell.
- Make the transition *opt-in* on a *per-code-unit* basis, where (new) code has to explicitly signal the desire to use PowerShell as the default shell.

Therefore, I think **you'll have to forgo the convenience of `shell_exec()` by using `exec()` with an explicit call to [PowerShell's CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) instead**; e.g., to execute commands `Get-Date; "Hello, world."; exit 42`:

```
<?php

exec('powershell -noprofile -command Get-Date; \"Hello, world.\"; exit 42', $output, $exitCode);

// Output the captured stdout lines and the exit code.
echo implode("\n", $output);
echo "\nExit code: " . $exitCode

?>
```

`exec()` generally has the advantage of being able to report the process' *exit code*, which `shell_exec()` cannot.

Use `-file` instead of `-command` if you're calling a *script file* (`*.ps1`).

To call PowerShell *Core* rather than Window PowerShell, use `pwsh.exe` instead of `powershell.exe`.

Note the perhaps surprising need to `\`-escape the embedded `"` chars. - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2361).

Comment: Well explained. Actually, there is no solutions. Huge breaking change and fast death, or slow and painful death. This is funny because they shot them self in perfect awareness. It's all done already.